# Google Chrome install fails with error 0x80004002

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, 64-bit

I'm using Windows 7 64 bits and I'm trying to install Google Chrome. However, every time I do, I get this error message:

> Google Update installation failed with error 0x80004002.

There is a *Show me help for this issue* link, but it does nothing.

I tried the standalone installer to no avail.

I also tried to delete the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Google` registry key, as suggested by other answers, with no more positive effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [downloaded the standalone installer for all users](http://support.google.com/installer/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=126299) and it worked. Since it needs administrator privileges to install for all users, it's probable that the non-standalone, single-user installer didn't work because administrator privileges were not explicitly granted.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help either. I still met the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue what did was copy an updated google chrome from my windows 8 and paste it on my win 7 os and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

**I got it working**, you may have a 64 bit PC so remember and download the 64 bit standalone version of Google Chrome, restart your computer into SAFE MODE, most PC's use F8 on the keyboard to bring up SAFE MODE, once in Windows, go to the standalone version of Chrome, right click it and use Administrator Privileges - then once installed, restart your computer till back in normal windows, hope it works for you